# Why does this remove all "%" lua

Tags: lua, obfuscation

So I am working on this obfuscator and when I add my encoding algorithm after the first ")" it removes all "%" in the algorithm, how do I fix this?

Here is the way i do it:

```
newScript = newScript:gsub('%)', algorithm , 1)
```

Comment: Can you give an example input and the resulting and expected output? Not entirely sure what your question is.

Comment: I want to add a line of code containing a "%" after the first ")" so after: return(function(...) The algorithm would be here

Comment: I assume you mean it removes all `)` instead of `%` your question mentions?

Comment: No? It adds a string after the first ")" but it also removes all the "%" for some reason

Comment: You need to escape each `%` that appears in the `algorithm` variable or use a method that does not use patterns

Comment: For a simple rotation (rot13 for chars, rot5 for numbers and rot8 for a fistfull signs) i use a table called ```rot```. To also hit spaces and other signs ( like the ```%``` ) i use the dot like in this example: ```('Text with %% and spaces and numbers 0123456789'):gsub('.',rot)``` - It returns: ```Grkg(jvgu(--(naq(fcnprf(naq(ahzoref(5678901234 46``` - The same code is used to rotate it back to: ```Text with %% and spaces and numbers 0123456789 46``` - So i suggest you alter your ```algoritm``` for use it with ```gsub('.',algorithm)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest reading the PIL regarding [captures](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html). The symbol `%` is a special character, therefore you need to escape it:

```lua
newScript = newScript:gsub('%)', algorithm:gsub('%%', '%%%%'), 1)
```

This replaces every `%` in your replacement string with `%%`, which will then become `%` when used as replacement in `newScript`.

The PIL even clearly says:

> By the way, because of those changes, a `%´ in the replacement string
> must be escaped as "%%".